# Python mongoengine - GET ID of the last entry

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a scenario where i need to create a clone of few products in my mongoDB. I use the following code

```
    for single_product in survey_products:
        cloned_product = without_keys(single_product, {'_id'})
        cloned_product_doc = Product(**cloned_product)
        cloned_product_doc.save()
        print(cloned_product_doc.id)
        print(cloned_product_doc._id)
```

This creates the records properly which is alright, but in both the `print` functions, i get `None` even though i call `cloned_product_doc.save()` prior to accessing the `IDs`

How can i get the `ID` of the new entries?

**EDITED**

Here is the model definition

```
class Product(Document):
# model
_id = ObjectIdField()
photo = StringField()
name = StringField()
price = FloatField()
currency = StringField()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'product'
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit the model definition like below, make sure you define the ObjectId as the default

```
.........................
from mongoengine import *
from bson import ObjectId
#import objectID to use as default

class Product(Document):
# model
_id = ObjectIdField(default=ObjectId)  # mention default as ObjectId
photo = StringField()
name = StringField()
price = FloatField()
currency = StringField()
class Meta:
    db_table = 'product'
```

Answer (score 1):

Under normal usage, Mongoengine adds the id to the instance when you call .save().

```
from mongoengine import *

connect()

class MyDoc(Document):
    # Mongoengine adds an id = ObjectIdField if no 'id' is provided
    s = StringField()

doc = MyDoc(s='garbage').save()
print(doc.id)    # e.g 600df8c3d87af06b92725f87
```

I would suggest to inspect what is in your `cloned_product`. Perhaps there is a remaining 'id' key or something that interferes with default behavior

Comment: nope, the `cloned_product` has no `id` or `_id` key

Comment: edited the question with model definition as well

Comment: I would also avoid using "_id", use "id" in the model definition. MongoEngine is managing an attribute "_id" behind the scene, perhaps you are interfering with that. Also MongoEngine has no support for defining Meta as a class (it's a simple dict, see https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#document-collections) so your Meta is currently ignored